# Почему если вывести компоненту с помощью this он ее выведет в виде массива, а без нее в виде текста ? JS

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
const video = {
            title: 'a',
            play() {
                console.log(this);
            }
        };
        video.play();
```

В консоли выводит: {title: 'a', play: ƒ}

Если вместо this, написать просто video.play, выведет: a

По сути я вызываю ту же константу, но в результате данные отличаются, почему так это особенности JS или я чего-то не понимаю ?

Comment: this в данном случае - video. а video.play - это его метод. Разные и оба два совсем не константы.

Comment: Спасибо, за объяснение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const video = {}
```

это объект

```
play() {}
```

это функция которая  создаётся внутри объекта и применяется к этому объекту (метод).

```
video.play();
```

Выполнить метод "play" для объекта "video".

```
play(){
  console.log(this)
  }
```

В данном случае, "this" это обращение к объекту внутри которого выполняется эта строка кода, к объекту "video". Дословно:

```
    показать в консоли(этот объект)
```

[Хорошая статья на Хабре про "this"](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/419371/)

Comment: Спасибо, за объяснение